# CONCAT values in specific cells based off values in a different column

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

I need help and apologies in advance for not including a code because I do not know where to even start.

I work as a reporting analyst and have a table full of customer data + customer remarks. I need to contact the customer remarks and cannot think of a way to do so.

My table has 7 columns and I need to concatenate the REMARK_TEXTS rows before sending the report off to our internal clients.

The remarks are based on the REMARKS_SEQ_NBR column and the sequence numbers aligned with the REMARK TEXTS. I am including a screenshot of an excel mockup I created.

This is my query using LISTAGG():

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AA.ID_NUMBER,
AA.LAST_NAME,
AA.FIRST_NM,
AA.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
AA.CUSTOMER_SINCE,
AA.REMARKS_SEQ_NBR
LISTAGG(‘REMARK_TEXTS’
) WITHIN GROUP (
AA.ID_NUMBER
)
AS CUSTOMERS
FROM CUSTOMER_CURRENT
GROUP BY ID_NUMBER
ORDER BY ID_NUMBER
```

Thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYbmf.png)

Comment: [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. And include both sample data and expected result as formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: You might be able to use `listagg()`, ordered by seq_nbr, if the total length is within limits (or can be truncated). But without clear data and results (as text) it's hard to be sure.

Comment: You are likely going to have to listagg() or remove your `remarks_ses_nbr` too. As long as that is left in the SELECT as-is you are not going to be aggregating records (assuming that `remarks_seq_nbr` is part of the uniqueness of the record.

Comment: There are lots of issues with the code you added - missing comma, wrong quotes (though not needed at all), group-by not matching non-aggregate select list columns, no ordering within listagg... If you provide textual sample data and results as requested we can run the query and tell you how to get it to do what you want. (You might also want to consider normalising your data - if you must split remarks into multiple rows, they should probably be in a separate table, linked via just ID.)

Comment: Like `SELECT id_number, last_name, first_nm, date_of_birth, customer_since, LIST_AGG(Remark_Texts) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY remarks_seq_nbr) as remarks FROM CUSTOMERS GROUP BY id_number, last_name, first_nm, date_of_birth, customer_since ORDER BY id_number;`

Comment: @AlexPoole, I can't provide the actual textual sample data due to confidentiality. It's for my job. I had to recreate the data after changing the names of the columns and the actual data.

Comment: It doesn't have to be real data, it can be representative - but as text, not an image of an Excel sheet; and with matching expected results.

Comment: @AlexPoole

SELECT DISTINCT
AA.ID_NUMBER,
AA.LAST_NAME,
AA.FIRST_NM,
AA.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
AA.CUSTOMER_SINCE,
AA.REMARKS_SEQ_NBR
LISTAGG(‘REMARK_TEXTS’
) WITHIN GROUP (
AA.ID_NUMBER
)
AS CUSTOMERS
FROM CUSTOMER_CURRENT
GROUP BY ID_NUMBER
ORDER BY ID_NUMBER

Comment: @AlexPoole I posted an image of the data on my main question.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to combine multiple rows into one, so you need an aggregate function. For concatenating text, that's `LISTAGG`. You have it pretty much right:

```
select id_number, last_name, first_name, date_of_birth, customer_since
       listagg( trim( remark_texts ), ' ' ) within group ( order by remarks_seq_nbr )
           as customers
  from customer_current
 group by id_number, last_name, first_name, date_of_birth, customer_since
 order by id_number
```

I'm trimming the text and using space as a separator, so you don't wind up with `CUSTOMER PREFERS DONOT CALL`.